# Synergy Connection refused (Also telnet)

Tags: fedora, synergy

I recently switched distros to fedora (was looking for the most recent version of eclipse being supported, something I wasn't getting from Debian), and in trying to get synergy set up again, I've been having an issue where my synergy server is refusing the connection from my macbook.

My synergy.conf file:

```
section: screens
    client1:
    server:
end
section: aliases
    client1:
        macname
    server:
        linuxname   
end
section: links
    client1:
        left = server
    server:
        right= client1
end
```

My synergys command:

```
synergys -f -c /path/to/synergy.conf
```

My synergyc command:

```
synergyc -f linuxname
```

Both computers can ping each other, and on the linux computer I've used

```
telnet localhost 24800
```

which confirms that synergys is running (also ps -Af | grep synergys).

On the mac, when I try to do

```
telnet linuxname 24800
```

I get the message

```
telnet: connect to address ip.of.linux.box: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

$ sudo netstat -pant | grep 24800
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:24800 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 22727/synergys
```

Both versions of Synergy report themselves as 1.3.7, protocol 1.3 .

I'm at a loss.  Anyone got a bright idea or two?

Comment: On the linux box, can you run `sudo netstat -pant | grep 24800` and post it here?

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:24800               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22727/synergys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this was a firewall issue.  I guess I was firewall-less on my previous (debian) installation (or the port was already open).  I opened `port 24800` using `system-config-firewall`, and it just plain worked.

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting connection refused rather than a timeout, I suspect it is an issue with host access control rather than a firewall issue.  If these files exist, please make sure that the deny file do not contain any blocks:

```
 /etc/hosts.allow
 /etc/hosts.deny
```

So comment out any lines containing `ALL`

Comment: There's nothing in either file besides "# hosts.allow   This file contains access rules which are used to
#               allow or deny connections to network services that
#               either use the tcp_wrappers library or that have been
#               started through a tcp_wrappers-enabled xinetd.
#
#               See 'man 5 hosts_options' and 'man 5 hosts_access'
#               for information on rule syntax.
#               See 'man tcpd' for information on tcp_wrappers
#
~                                                                  "

Comment: host.conf does say "multi on"

Comment: Synergy does not use *tcpwrappers*; the `hosts.allow`/`.deny` files are not being used. `host.conf` contains DNS resolver configuration and is completely irrelevant.